# How can I connect my netlify project URL/domain to firebase?

Tags: firebase-authentication, dns, firebase-hosting, netlify, custom-domain

I am new to this and have a basic project url like abcxyz.netlify.app. I have firebase authentication and need to connect the domain to firebase. But, it says I need to 'add the TXT records below to your DNS provider to verify that you own netlify.app'. How do I do it?  If there's an alternate way, then please suggest it!

the netlify docs suggest me to go to netlity website, then Teams > Domains > Add or register domain to add the TXT records. But upon adding the domain, it says "A DNS zone for this domain already exists under a different account". What to do?